# Появляется обводка у панели при создании своей темы в Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, extension, themes

Имею такой `manifest.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "Theme",
    "description": "Theme",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "theme": {
        "images": {
            "theme_toolbar": "/images/theme_toolbar.png"
        },
        "colors": {
            "background_tab": [30, 30, 30],
            "background_tab_inactive": [30, 30, 30],
            "background_tab_incognito": [30, 30, 30],
            "background_tab_incognito_inactive": [30, 30, 30],

            "tab_background_text": [170, 170, 170],
            "tab_background_text_inactive": [170, 170, 170],
            "tab_background_text_incognito": [170, 170, 170],
            "tab_background_text_incognito_inactive": [170, 170, 170],

            "tab_text": [220, 66, 66],
            "toolbar_text": [220, 66, 66],

            "bookmark_text": [150, 150, 150],

            "frame": [10, 10, 10],
            "frame_inactive": [10, 10, 10],
            "frame_incognito": [10, 10, 10],
            "frame_incognito_inactive": [10, 10, 10],

            "ntp_background": [10, 10, 10],
            "ntp_header": [10, 10, 10],
            "ntp_link": [6, 55, 116],
            "ntp_text": [0, 0, 0],

            "omnibox_background": [25, 25, 25],
            "omnibox_text": [190, 190, 190],

            "toolbar": [35, 35, 35],
            "toolbar_button_icon": [220, 66, 66]
        }
    }
}
```

`theme_toolbar.png`:

[image: theme_toolbar.png]

Почему-то получается такая обводка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался изменять другую тему, но в итоге эта линия тоже появилась, хоть я и добавлял построчно, после удаления последних изменений, линия по прежнему оставалась и уходить уже не хотела.
Как ее можно убрать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашел случайно на английском стэке. Необходимо было добавить больше контрастности между `toolbar` и `frame`.